# Global.onStop() not getting called on reload in dev mode

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.2

Using Play Framework 2.2.1 on MacOS X 10.8.4 with scala 2.10.3, I have this code:

```
package controllers

import play.api._

object Global extends GlobalSettings {

  override def onStart(app: Application) {
    Logger.info("Application has started")
  }

  override def onStop(app: Application) {
    Logger.info("Application shutdown...")
    Store.shutdown()
    Logger.info("Shutdown complete")
  }
}
```

When I use dev mode with `play run`, I get the following:

```
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/jon/code/test/project
[info] Set current project to critter (in build file:/Users/jon/code/test/)

--- (Running the application from SBT, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

[info] play - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0%0:9000

(Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)

[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/jon/code/test/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[info] play - Application started (Dev)
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/jon/code/test/target/scala-2.10/classes...

--- (RELOAD) ---

[info] play - Application started (Dev)
```

As you can see here, I triggered a request, which caused the app to be compiled and the request was then handled. I inserted a newline into a source file and made the request again, to trigger the reload. *I do not get a message concerning Application shutdown.*

I'm using an embedded database, so I need to close it gracefully. If I can't catch shutdown, I can't do that. Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug with Play and auto-reload?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It does not always necessarily need to be in the default/root package. If you want to keep it in controllers package like you did, you need to change the configuration for global in your application.conf from:

`global = Global` to
`global = controllers.Global`

It's just that the default to Global is root package.

Answer (score 0):

D'oh! Figured it out not long after posting. Quoth [the docs](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaGlobal):

> This object must be defined in the default (empty) package...

Removing the `package controllers` directive above fixed things right up.